# How to fix console error "_tfa is not defined" using GTM

Tags: javascript, console, google-tag-manager

I'm receiving a console error: "_tfa is not defined" and I can't find any fix for it or why I'm getting this error. This is related to Google Analitics (GTM).

This is the screen print:

[image: Console error]

[image: Console error detail]

Nothing fouded to fix this

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like an error made somewhere in GTM's custom code.

1. Log in into your GTM. Make sure the container ID is what you're
   debugging, so W9B277 in your case.
2. Then go to Admin and export your container's json.
3. Open the json and look for "visita_cualificada".
4. Json contains the information on what variable/rule/template it's in. Open it in GTM and decide what you want to do with it.

Comment: Hi. The GTM account is manage by the client and I cant access to it. Is there any other way to know whats the problem?

Comment: There's a parser that allows you to parse third party GTMs: https://gtmspy.com/ You can find the error that way, and then ask client to fix it. You could also prevent loading the client's GTM completely. Also you could probably add the object client's GTM tries to find on the page.